# Can I track hypersonic missiles with heat sensors?

Tags: plasma-physics, radar

On a video, it is said that hypersonic missiles create an plasma layer that scatters radar waves, therefore hard to detect

And then, on another video, it demonstrates anti-ballistic missile system that partially utilizes heat detectors to track its ascent portion.

My question is, why don’t we use the same heat sensors to track the plasma layer around the missile, and knock it out?

Comment: IDK, but so-called "hypersonic missiles" supposedly are maneuverable. If "maneuvering" includes [_jinking_](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jink) to avoid enemy defenses, and if it's approaching at hypersonic speeds, that's going to be somewhat of a difficult target to hit.

Comment: One would need links to the videos cited, to have a meaningful discussion.

Comment: Much of the relevant info on hypersonic missiles is apparently classified, i.e., I do not know why we cannot track them but colleagues of mine with security clearances say that we cannot but cannot specify why.

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically, plasma can reduce the radar cross section of a missile under certain circumstances, for certain frequencies. Under other circumstances, it can *increase* it. To the best of my knowledge, there is no publicly-available evidence that any missile that actually takes advantage of this fact exists, or that it would be effective across the whole range of radar bands actually used in the military.

There's a bigger problem anyway. Ground-based radar and heat detection alike are not very useful against hypersonic because they are line-of-sight, and these missiles fly low to the ground. By the time it comes over the horizon, it's already far too late to do anything about it.

Comment: How about satielletes then